# :not() in various guises isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm making a simple jQuery navigation system but I am far from expert at it, as the following code may demonsytrate..

HTML:

```
  <ul id="main-nav"> 
        <li><a href="../" id="home">HOME</a></li> 
        <li class="pipe">|</li> 
        <li id="about">ABOUT US</li> 
        <li class="pipe">|</li> 
        <li id="projects">PROJECT TYPES</li> 
        <li class="pipe">|</li>             
        <li id="reducing">REDUCING EMISSIONS</li> 
        <li class="pipe">|</li> 
        <li id="carbon">CARBON MARKETS</li> 
        <li class="pipe">|</li> 
        <li id="FAQs">FAQs</li> 
    </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#main-nav li:not('.pipe')").hover(function () {
            var $this = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#nav-strip2 ul.sub-nav').hide();
            $("#nav-" + $this).show();
        });
    });
```

The showing/hiding works just fine, the only issue is when the pipe is hovered over it hides everything. There's a reason the menu needs to be made up in `<li>`s and can't just be `<a>`s but it's not really relevant and long.

I'm trying here to exclude the .hover() stuff from happening when it's a li with .pipe class but there's no joy. What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated. I'm sure there's a way of excluding `<li>`s with no ID attached, which would save assigning the .pipe class to all those `<li>`s. Alas I have not the jQuery ability to figure this out yet!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using [`:not()` as a selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector), don't use quotes within its brackets:

```
$("#main-nav li:not(.pipe)")
```

Comment: also sorry about the mega formatting fail in my post, new to all this. very impressed though!

Comment: @user713901: No problem - you can refer to this when writing future posts: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#main-nav li").not('.pipe').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#nav-strip2 ul.sub-nav').hide();
        $("#nav-" + this.id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why would you assign an ID attribute to a variable named `$this`? I would expect `var $this = $(this), id = this.id;` - yes, that's right, **you don't need jQuery to get an element's ID.**

Comment: excellent, 2 lessons for the price of one, thanks! i'm quickly starting to realise jQuery is amazing!

Comment: @Matt, yes i realized that after i posted it :-X thats true too, i was just copy/pasting the OP's code and tweaking it a bit